# Factorization Machines with some some pairwaise effects and some linear effects

Tags: machine-learning, python, recommender-system

I have some covariates $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, .., $x_{10}$. I want a linear term for all these covariates and a pairwise effect for $x_1$ and $x_2$, and I do not want any other pairwise effect. Is there an implementation of Factorization Machines I can use to achieve this?